# How to set format on text field?

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I have a form build in WordPress with contact form 7. I have put a custom validation on text field.

```
$("input[name='num'").keyup(function(e){

        var cpf = jQuery(this).val();
        if(cpf){
            var reg = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[.]?([0-9]{3})[.]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{2})$/;   
            if(!reg.test(cpf)) {

                jQuery("#cpf-error").html("Format Should be (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx)");

            }else{
                jQuery("#cpf-error").empty();
            }
        }


    });
```

With this validation format of number will be xxx.xxx.xxx-xx But in this case user have to type dots (.) and minus (-) to get his number validate. I want user to type only like this 12345678900 and it automatically converted like this 123.456.789-00 in text field.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Must input match exactly 11 numeric characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
document.getElementById("inputId").onkeyup = function(){
   this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2}).*/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='inputId' />
```

You can also try using the **CPF** mask of the [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: Haider, i did update the answer. You have to enter all the 11 digits in order to apply the mask to the number. Hope it helps.